# CMS, Backend for iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, content-management-system, backend

My question might be too easy. But i come from web development background and just started creating iOS app by learning from here and there. I have made 2 prototypes, but the second one need backend, cms.

From my prev experience i used php, mysql, html, css. I custom made the cms to organize my content and all user data, etc would be stored into database and can be maintained from the cms.

I use swift, but i seem to miss something important. in ios area what are the tools to develop the db (not local storage, coredata, and such) and maintain that; like what i used to use in web dev area? i dont even know how to ask the right question, but i really hope you guys would understand

can you guys give me direction? a link to basic knowledge of this will be fine

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think usually it will be database on a server and you will send requests and get answers in JSON format. You will have to parse them and use in your app.

Comment: Did you mean PARSE? instead of pars? i read about it from some articles that it has closed down

Comment: @KhomeiniSyahril "to parse" is an English verb

Comment: @KhomeiniSyahril yes to parse- to take and use values which you need from JSON